# Python random answering program

Tags: python, random

I wrote this programm

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
"""
import random
def CollectStrings():
   string_list = []
   while True:
      string = raw_input("What is your question: (enter to quit): ")
      if not string:
         return string_list
      string_list.append(string)

def ChooseStrings(how_many):
  string_list = CollectStrings()
  chosen = random.sample(string_list, how_many)
  chosen.sort()
  return ', '.join(chosen)

print ChooseStrings (3)
```

But I need to make this program randomly answer questions, like an 8ball. 
How would I do that?

Comment: You should rephrase your question to something specific. "Can you write this program for me" isn't specific. What do you understand about your program? Where do you think the issue is? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Add all answers to a list and than use [random.choices](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) to get a random answer:

```
import random

answers = [
    "The answer lies in your heart",
    "I do not know",
    "Almost certainly",
    "No",
    "Yes",
    "Why do you need to ask?",
    "Go away. I do not wish to answer at this time.",
    "Time will only tell",
]
print random.choice(answers) // Print random answer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=['answers']
#create a list of answers
q=['questions']
#create a list of questions
import random
x=input('your question')
if x in q:
    print(random.choice(q))
```